# Is there a cross-browser solution to get the length of an element's attributes array

Tags: attributes

I'd tried to arrange a cross-browser function to count the attributes of an element. The problem is that IE does not support the "attributes" function which is supported by the leading browsers and returns an array. Instead I used getAttribute(), which doesn't return an array, but only gets the value of an attribute I'm looking for. Is there any other function equivalent, or maybe a method, that is simpler than creating an array of possible atts and check through getAttribute for each?

I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 0):

`attributes` should be supported by all browsers. Maybe it does not work, because you assume it to be a function and try to call it like one. It is actuall an array. So this should do:

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].attributes.length)
```

(Note how there are no `()` after `.attributes`.)

---

Whoops, I just saw that IE is indeed [incompatible](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes) here (can't test, I'm on Linux). Sorry about that.

Comment: `allNodes = ( document.all || document.getElementsByTagName( "*" ) );
for( j = 0 , allNodesL = allNodes.length ; j < allNodesL ; j++ ){
 if( allNodes[ j ][ this[ 0 ] ] && true == false ){
  if( allNodes[ j ][ this[ 0 ] ] == this[ 1 ] ) return allNodes[ j ];
 }
  
 else{
 atts = ( allNodes[ j ].attributes || allNodes[ j ].getAttribute );
 }
blah blah`